# Redirect/Security Issue With Website Link

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, redirect, https

I'm running into a rather annoying problem with my website.

I have a valid SSL certificate running on my domain but every time I try to manually access a certain page from my website it appears as non-ssl.

If I browse the pages starting from my homepage they all appear to be fine but if I  go directly to a page the browser tells me that is not secured.

The odd thing is that this only happens when I type the link without "https/https" and www. Ex: "mywebsite.com/my-page". 
If I'm entering "www" before the domain name or http/https it redirects to the secure version.

As a side note, I'm using WordPress as my CMS.

I would highly appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force https by adding the following to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```